# Xcode - How to test different test targets together

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, swift-package-manager

I'm using SPM to achieve modular architecture in my iOS Xcode project. That's my `package.swift`:

```
let targets: [Target] = [
    .target(name: "Home", dependencies: ["Texture", ...]),
    .testTarget(name: "HomeTests", dependencies: ["Home", ...]),
    .target(name: "Inbox", dependencies: []),
    .testTarget(name: "Inbox”Tests", dependencies: ["Inbox", ...]),
    .target(name: “Settings”, dependencies: []),
    .testTarget(name: "SettingsTests", dependencies: ["Settings", ...]),
]

let package = Package(
    name: "MyPackage",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v14), .macOS(.v10_15)],
    products: targets.filter { !$0.isTest }.map { .library(name: $0.name, targets: [$0.name]) },
    dependencies: [...],
    targets: targets)
)
```

As you can see I have test target for each module. TestTargets contain unit tests.
How can I run all the test targets together? For now I can only run each test target independently and it takes too much time to test the whole app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a test plan and edit the current scheme and add the tests you want to run in the test phase:

1.- Edit the scheme
[image: Edit the scheme]

2.- Add the test plan here
[image: Add the test plan here]

3.- Add the test targets into the test plan
[image: Add the test targets into the test plan]

4.- Optionally you can gather coverage in the test plan by going into the "Configurations" tab.